# Splitting a Multi-dimensional array VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to write a function that can do Dot Product calculations on arrays. I want to use the SumProduct worksheet function to do this. I demonstrated what I'm trying to do on the worksheet with the attached image:

[image: SumProduct]

I want to do this using VBA, and for each column of W. The issue is that W is a two dimensional array and I need to split each column into its own array. I'm not sure how to do this efficiently.

Any thoughts on how I can split W column wise?

Edit: I know that you can loop through W, and assign each column to temporary array for calculations. However, I'm curious if this can be done without a loop. I'm writing a Neural Network so performance is important. (VBA is the only language I have at the office, otherwise I'd use Python.)

Edit: Thank you for the assist friends. Based on the Application.Index() suggestion I went ahead and tried to implement it.

```
Dim w() As Double: ReDim w(3, 3)
For i = 0 To UBound(w)
    For ii_ = 0 To UBound(w, 2)
        w(i, ii) = 0.01
    Next
Next

Dim a() As Double: ReDim a(3)
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    a(i) = 0.03
Next

Dim b() As Double: ReDim b(3)
For i = 0 To UBound(b)
    b(i) = 0.03
Next

'assign each column of w to L 
Dim L() As Double: ReDim L(UBound(a))
For i = 0 To UBound(w, 2)
    L(i) = Application.Index(w, 0, 1)
Next
```

I am getting a type mismatch error on Application.Index(). The idea is to use L() like so:

```
'linear activation
Dim Z() as Double: redim Z(ubound(a))
for i = 0 to ubound(Z)
    Z(i) = Worksheetfunction.SumProduct(L, a) + b(i)
next
```

Haven't gotten far enough to test this out though. Any thoughts on how to get .Index() to work?

Comment: If you are going the route of worksheetfunctions, you can use `INDEX()`.

Comment: Looping should be pretty fast though.

Comment: What that "W" is? Is it the row where it appears in your picture? What multi-dimensional array are you referring to?

Comment: `Application.Index(w, 0, 1)` etc ?

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get .Index to work? I tried using it in my code and I get a 'type mismatch error'. I put my code in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to be close to your original code and assuming the  array `b` elements to represent single values added as sort of constant during each new calculation:

- declare arrays as variant
- and as 1-based 2-dimensional as it facilitates operations together with `Application.Index` (which result in 1-based arrays)

```
Dim w: ReDim w(1 To 4, 1 To 4)
Dim i As Long, ii As Long
For i = LBound(w) To UBound(w)
    For ii = LBound(w, 2) To UBound(w, 2)
        w(i, ii) = 0.01 * i + ii
    Next
Next

Dim a: ReDim a(1 To 4, 1 To 1)
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    a(i, 1) = 0.03
Next

Dim b: ReDim b(1 To 4, 1 To 1)
For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
    b(i, 1) = 0.03
Next

'assign each column of w to L
Dim L As Variant: ReDim L(1 To UBound(a))
For i = LBound(w, 2) To UBound(w, 2)
     L(i) = Application.Index(w, 0, i)
     Debug.Print "[" & i & "] ", _
         WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(L(i), a) + b(i, 1)
Next
```

Anyway personally I'd prefer pure array calculations multiplying factors via a function.

Comment: @lazylama FYI Posted a solution close to OP a week ago - feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark and/or to upvote if helpful.